# Conditional 'click' binding with Knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I am binding the click event to every list item in a list:

```
        <ul class="modal-subject-list" data-bind="foreach: filteredSubjects">
            <li data-bind="click: $parent.pickSubject, css: {alreadyAddedBackground: hasBeenAdded}">
                <!-- Lots of code here -->
            </li>
        </ul>
```

I want to disable the `click:` binding if 'hasBeenAdded' resolves to true.  I know some messy ways to take care of it:

1. Have two list items, one for `if: hasBeenAdded`, and the other for `if: !hasBeenAdded`.  This is far from DRY
2. Handle this check with javascript and leave the view alone - I don't like this because unnecessary markup is being generated for list items that should be essentially disabled.

Is there a way to register a "clickIf" binding?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Do this

```
    <ul class="modal-subject-list" data-bind="foreach: filteredSubjects">
        <li data-bind="click: hasBeenAdded ? null : $parent.pickSubject">
            <!-- Lots of code here -->
        </li>
    </ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7hcj6/

Read -

If the filteredSubject has been added, do nothing, else add to the list or whatever.

Comment: A button that does nothing when you click is hardly user friendly, better just to use the enable/disble binding

Comment: OP was very specific in that he wanted to conditionally handle the click binding, whether he uses null or not in a production environment is his choice...

Comment: it's better to replace "null" with function, <li data-bind="click: hasBeenAdded ? function() { return false; } : $parent.pickSubject">

Comment: @Kishor, Could you please explain why it is better?

Comment: Be careful, using the function returning false has a completely different meaning. If there is `null`, knockout will not bind anything to the event. When you pass that kind of function, for example the default event will be prevented to say the least.

Comment: Also note, that knockout is not treating event bindings as `computeds`, which means that the first result which your expression evaluates to will be used by knockout for the whole lifetime. You cannot do something like this for example: `data-bind="click: myObservable() ? null : myHandler"` and expect that the handler will get bound and unbound based on the expression. This was kind of a surprise for me, but I guess it would add a big amount of complexity to implement properly.

Answer (score 1):

**Just want to expand on @PW Kad's answer in case it helps others.**

I found that I could apply a condition to the knockout event node so that all or none of the handlers are bound.  In my case, I needed to bind events only to inputs that were not read only.  So this does work if you need to do something similar. *Happy coding.*

event: $data.SomeProperty() ? null : { multiple event handlers }

**Example Code:**

```
<input type="number"
       data-bind="value: $data.Value,
                  css: $data.Css,
                  attr: {
                      title: $data.Title,
                      min: $data.Min,
                      max: $data.Max,
                      readonly: $data.ReadOnly
                  },
                  event: $data.ReadOnly() ? null : {  // <----- HERE
                      focus: $root.onFocus,
                      blur: $root.onBlur,
                      input: $root.onInput,
                      keypress: $root.onKeypress
                   }" />
```

Comment: I'm not the biggest fan of that a large chunk of our application uses knockout at work, but you sir, showed me something that now seems so obvious. Thank you!