# Conditionally active click event on js button

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I need a function on a button only if a bool conditional is met. Currently I have it implemented similar to

```
<button class="btn btn--primary pull-right" type="submit" data-bind="click: myBoolFlag ? $root.myFunction : function(){}"/>
```

I am using this button as my generic submit button on multiple pages, but on two of them it merely needs to add in a small function on click ontop of its normal submit functionality.

I feel as though doing this via an anonymous empty function isn't the best route, and am looking for cleaner alternatives.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional 'click' binding with Knockout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18970244/conditional-click-binding-with-knockout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this situation I usually do something like so..

**HTML**

```
<!-- I gave it an ID to make it unique -->
<button id="myButton" class="btn btn--primary pull-right" type="submit"/>
```

**JavaSCript/jQuery**

```
//this handles the click function now
$('#myButton').click(function() {
  if(condiion1){
   do this;
  } else {
    do that;
  } 
});
```

Comment: Sweet, glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Try returning true if you don't want to a function to be executed on click

```
<button class="btn btn--primary pull-right" type="submit" data-bind="click: myBoolFlag ? $root.myFunction : return true;"/>
```

Other option would be null

```
data-bind="click: myBoolFlag ? $root.myFunction : null"
```

Comment: That just creates a sytanx error. Id have to write the return true in the anonymous function which really doesn't change the solution at all.

Comment: Then you can pass parameter to the function and then decide. something like this -  click: function () { $root.myFunction (myBoolFlag ); }